# i have authentication problems with cosmosdb connection

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-cosmosdb

im trying to connect to cosmosdb and i get the following error:

```
System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/daniel.documents.azure.com:10255" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/daniel.documents.azure.com:10255", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

update:
i'm using persistence with NServiceBus.
can it be that this is the problem?
do you know if NServiceBus supports AZURE CosmosDB?

Comment: Could you please provide more info? How are you trying to connect? What are he options you are using?

Comment: im trying to connect from azure environment and with ssl. also im using mongodb driver 2.4. im connecting with the connection string provided from azure portal.

Comment: You might want to try emailing AskCosmosDB@microsoft.com. You haven't provided any source code/etc. or an example of your connection string, so it's pretty hard to guess what might be going wrong from the current question. Needs more info.

Comment: mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
MongoServer server = mongoClient.GetServer();                        
databaseMongoDB = server.GetDatabase(Database_Name);   
                                                                                         
i have also tried with :
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
var server = mongoClient.GetServer();
var db = server.GetDatabase(Database_Name);